# Is there a way to highlight overlapping participants in a Google Sheets plan with conditional formatting or a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, overlap

I have a plan with time, event, participants and room in Google Sheets. Now it would be very practical if Sheets could recognise as soon as I have scheduled several participants in the same time period or if the different time periods overlap with the same people.
The participants are a string in which the abbreviations of the people are separated by a space.

I tried two ideas on how it could work. One is via conditional formatting, which then automatically highlights somewhere (for example directly the participant field) as soon as an overlap forms.

On the other hand, a script would also be possible, which I activate via a button and which checks the time periods for the participants and marks the corresponding participant field in case of overlaps.

[screenshot from table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooF8z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is absolutely feasible. There are two easy ways to go about it based on the info you provided, the first is with iteration:

```js
function checkSchedulingIteration() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(YOUR SHEET NAME);
  const lowerY = 1; // your starting row, mine is 1 in this instance. looks like yours is 244
  const upperY = sheet.getLastRow(); // amount of rows

  for (let x = lowerY; x <= upperY; ++x) {
    const startTime = new Date(sheet.getRange(`B${x}`).getValue());
    const endTime = new Date(sheet.getRange(`C${x}`).getValue());
    const nextStartTimeRange = sheet.getRange(`B${x + 1}`);
    const nextStartTime = new Date(nextStartTimeRange.getValue());

    if (nextStartTime > startTime &&  nextStartTime < endTime) nextStartTimeRange.setBackground('red');
  }
}
```

This is going to iterate over every timeframe and the start of the next timeframe & check if the start of the next timeframe falls within the first timeframe; if so, the conflicting time will be marked red.

the second is with a custom formula:

```js
function checkSchedulingFormula(startTime, endTime, nextStartTime) {
  if (nextStartTime > startTime &&  nextStartTime < endTime) return `sheduling error at ${nextStartTime}`;
}
```

This is going to require another column to output the result, you can apply it like this:

`=checkSchedulingFormula(click on your starting time, click on your ending time, click on your next starting time)`

this will end up looking something like this:

`=checkSchedulingFormula(B244, C244, B245)`

You will need to adjust your `lowerY` and `upperY` according to the architecture of your workbook.

Lastly, in the future please write a more thorough question; per stackoverflow

> Summarize the problem

> Describe what you’ve tried

> Show some code